# Python program returning None Type array when append to the list

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, nonetype

My python program has a minor problem. The case is that I'm trying to use `myarray.append()` to my array, but in the python shell, it's telling me this when I do a test appending in the python shell:

```
>> l.append('1') # l is already defined

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>

    l.append('1')

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
>>
```

I'm very confused about this problem, but anyways, I'll let you see the code:

```
l=[] #*
i=1
while True:
  if 3*i<1000:
    l.append(str(i)) #*
  else:
    break
  i+=1
l=l.sort()
print l
```

***I believe here are the main factors of the problem**

I might just be going crazy and not realizing, but if you can help, please do.

P.S. When I run the program, on `print l`, it just output's `None`

Comment: Your code is not working as it is, this will end up in a infinte loop `i+=1` is outside of the while...

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in

```
l = l.sort()
```

The sort() method sorts a list in-place; the list itself is reordered, rather than returning a new list. The method returns None, which you are then assigning to `l`. So you just need to remove the assignment.

An alternative is to use

```
l = sorted(l)
```

which will actually make a copy of the original list with the elements in sorted order.

Comment: Except that this statement is never reached, at least in the code as presented.

Comment: @SimonBowly So it there a way of not making it repeat?

Comment: @ScottHunter: In the code as presented, it's an infinite loop; I suspect there are major indentation errors, either in the original code, or in a poor copy/paste job.

Comment: @ShadowRanger it's the poor copy/paste job... sorry

Comment: @Supercoolbat I assumed it was just a copy-paste issue, otherwise you would be asking why the program never terminated! Your `i=i+1` statement needs to be inside the while loop but outside the if/else. You have indented it 2 spaces too far.

Answer (score 1):

In python, you can populate a list as follows with a `list comprehension`

```
l = [str(i) for i in range(0, 1000)]
l > ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ..]
```

If you use `sort` in a list, it returns `None` which is an indicator in python, that it does the operation in place. So to print a sorted list, it's enough to do:

```
l.sort()
print(l)
```