# How do I change my list element types from 'NoneType' to just Integers?

Tags: python

The following here is my code and the section where there is the issue I'm encountering is on line 19.

```
#Check It Out Python 3.5.2 program
import datetime
import CheckItOutprogram
counter = 1

currentYear = datetime.date.today().year
currentMonth = datetime.date.today().month
dayOfMonth = datetime.date.today().day

name = input("Please input your name: ")
postCode = input("Please enter your postcode: ")
expiryYear = int(input("Please enter the year your card expires: "))
expiryMonth = int(input("Please enter the month your card expires: "))
expiryDay = int(input("Please enter the day of the month your card expires: "))
cardNo = input("Please enter your card number: ")
checkDigit = int(cardNo[7]) / 10
cardNo = list(cardNo)
cardNo = cardNo.reverse()
cardNoOdd = int(cardNo[0]) + int(cardNo[2]) + int(cardNo[4]) + int(cardNo[6])

#The three following IF statements check the expiry date.
if expiryYear > currentYear:
    print("I'm sorry, your card has expired.")
    again = input("Would you like to start again? Press enter to exit or type anything to start again: ")
    if again != "":
        exit()
    else:
        CheckItOutprogram.start()
if (expiryMonth >= currentMonth) and (expiryDay > dayOfMonth):
    print("I'm sorry, your card has expired.")
    again = input("Would you like to start again? Press enter to exit or type anything to start again: ")
    if again != "":
        exit()
    else:
        CheckItOutprogram.start()
if (expiryYear != isinstance(expiryYear, int)) or (expiryMonth != isinstance(expiryMonth, int)) or (expiryDay != isinstance(expiryDay, int)):
    print("I'm sorry, your card has expired.")
    again = input("Would you like to start again? Press enter to exit or type anything to start again: ")
    if again != "":
        exit()
    else:
        CheckItOutprogram.start()
#This IF statement checks the amount of characters the card number contains and makes sure that it has 8 elements.
if (len(cardNo) > 8) or (len(cardNo) * 8):
    print("Please try again...\n")
    CheckItOutprogram.start()

#This checks if the card is avaliable for a 10% discount using the last number.
if checkDigit == isinstance(checkDigit, int):
    print("This card is valid! This means that you may have a 10% discount off everything!")
    print("Here are the customer and loyalty card details. Name: " + name + ". Post Code:  " + postCode + ". Expiry Date: " + str(expiryDay) + "/" + str(expiryMonth) + "/" + str(expiryYear) + ". Card Number: " + cardNo)
else:
    print("I'm sorry, your card isn't qualified for a 10% discount.")
    again = input("Would you like to start again? Press enter to exit or type anything to start again: ")
    if again != "":
        exit()
```

Is there any way to change the list type from 'NoneType' to an Integer because I'm getting a frustrating error saying the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\Computer Science\Check It Out program\CheckItOutprogram.py", line 3, in <module>
    import CheckItOutprogram
  File "Z:\Computer Science\Check It Out program\CheckItOutprogram.py", line 20, in <module>
    cardNoOdd = int(cardNo[0]) + int(cardNo[2]) + int(cardNo[4]) + int(cardNo[6])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Is it possible to receive any extra information on how to improve my code, in what way as well as how to convert the 'cardNo' list from a 'NoneType' to something that IS subscriptable because I have tried everything possible. Also, if there is any room for feedback to improve the code efficiency, that would be very favourable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your problem is that `cardNo.reverse()` returns `None`. The list is reordered in place, so you should not assign the result back to `cardNo`

Comment: Very similar to `list.sort()` in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47544145/9017455).

Answer (score 0):

I got a result with the addition doing the following:

```
cardNo = str(input("Please enter your card number: "))
cardNo = list(cardNo)
cardNo = cardNo[::-1]
print(cardNo)
cardNoOdd = int(cardNo[0]) + int(cardNo[2]) + int(cardNo[4]) + int(cardNo[6])
print(cardNoOdd)


my input: Please enter your card number: 1548315414
out: ['4', '1', '4', '5', '1', '3', '8', '4', '5', '1']
out: 17
```

edit (sorry, forgot to explain): I did not use reverse itself, but I used indexing to reverse the list. Additionally, I defined the input as a string.

Hope this is what you were looking for!